# Banner slider for wordpress without plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I would like to include banner slider that will fit properly on my site http://wwww.virmodrosti.com index page.

I tried to insert some codes I found on the internet but somehow ruined my entire page.

Question 1: Is jQuery or CSS alone is a better choice for slider?

Question 2: Where can I get easy slider without plugin for my wordpress theme?

I need a slider to be just below the line `div id="content"` on the main index page. I would like to insert an 1188px wide image because my main wrapper width is 1180px. All I want is a simple slider that has option for aorund 5 posts, that will be manually setup. That's why I ask for a good PHP or HTML code that will work with my wordpress theme.

.

Comment: If you like to go with plugins there are many popular plugins like revolution slider, carousal slider, and so on.. which type of slider you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show me a Demo, what kind of slider you want. you can use slider Revolution For a simple slider.

Comment: I used css slider from codepen.io but it has many similar css entries as I currently have, that's probably what was causing the corruption.I should probably change css tags and rename them to avoid duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good basic slider. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

However, if you don't know how to develop your own plugin, then you are going to struggle to figure out how to control the content of the slider. Also if you are using someone elses code, isn't that just the same as using a plugin? Using a plugin means the code will be regularly updated, whereas if you use someone elses static code, then if it breaks you won't know what to do.

Comment: plugins usually cannot be modied easily because they have limited options that's why it's always better to use your own code and make custom theme. I wanted tp use pdf download options for each article for example, but rather leave it since it  requires too many customizations and usually it's better to start on your own.

Comment: Yes that's fine if you are able to code your own. Code your own solution then when you hit an issue show your code here and we can help you out. However your question suggests you are not able to develop your own plugin. So I would recommend looking in to Advanced Custom Fields. You will be able to achieve some complex content management solutions using it. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/